# Ethers.js token price chart

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain, ethers.js

I'm using Ethers.js to get the token price from BSC using `getReserves` successfully.

```js
  const nodeRandom = !node ? wssNodes() : node;
  const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(nodeRandom);
  const pairAddress = await pancake.getPair(token0, token1);

  if (pairAddress === "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000") {
    return {
      status: "Pair not found",
    };
  }

  const pairContract = new ethers.Contract(pairAddress, pancakePair, provider);
  const reserves = await pairContract.getReserves();
```

I want to create a price chart for that token, but I get into trouble when I don't know how to get the historical price data from BSC.

Does Ethers.js support getting the token price history, or should we store the price we get into our database? If then, is there any way we can build the price chart of a token from the very beginning of the first block when we don't have that in our DB?

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `blockTag` field of the `overrides` object - [docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract-functionsCall). It queries the node to return the value from a specific block instead of the current.

```
const reserves = await pairContract.getReserves({
    blockTag: <blockNumer>
});
```

Note that it depends on the node provider if they support these historical queries or not. Most providers support it only in higher tier plans or not at all.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have missed that when reading the docs. And yes, the node provider I am using does not support that. Can I fetch the node range and decode the inputData on each transaction to get the price data for the chart? This way seems like too much headache for me.